# How to extract values from a python list or numpy array using conditional checks by the application of numpy vectorization?

Tags: python, list, numpy, vectorization, nested-loops

I have the following code and I want to extract certain values from other lists that depends upon the given condition. But my data sets are huge ~ 1 million values in each list. Therefore this method of nested loop takes too long. Is there a vectorized or faster approach using Numpy that I can use to speed up my code as well as use less memory?

```
import random
import numpy as np

x=[random.randrange(0,10) for _ in range(0,100)]
y=[random.randrange(0,10) for _ in range(0,100)]
z=[random.randrange(0,10) for _ in range(0,100)]

x_unique=np.unique(x)

xx_list=[]
y_list=[]
z_list=[]

for i in range(len(x_unique)):
    xx_list.append([])
    y_list.append([])
    z_list.append([])

for ii, i in enumerate(x_unique):
        for j,k in enumerate(x):
            if i == k:
                xx_list[ii].append(x[j])
                y_list[ii].append(y[j])
                z_list[ii].append(z[j])
```

[EDIT: added an example of what to expect]

In the lists: y_list and z_list, I want to store values that correspond to same index numbers as stored in xx_list.

For example consider the following example lists:

```
x = [0.1,0.1,1,0.1,2,1,0.1]
y = [1.1,2.1,3,4,5,6,7]
z = [10,11,12,13.1,14,15,16]
```

Therefore, x_unique is the following:

```
x_unique = [0.1,1,2]
```

xx_list, y_list and z_list should contain the following:

```
xx_list = [[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],[1,1],[2]]
y_list = [[1.1,2.1,4,7],[3,6],[5]]
z_list = [[10,11,13.1,16],[12,15],[14]]
```

Comment: Can you describe what you want to achieve (what should be in `xx_list`, `y_list` and `z_list `)?

Comment: @cglacet Check my edit please. I have included an example of what I want the code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that takes roughly 400ms for 1M items working on python lists. And a solution that takes 100ms when working on numpy arrays.

#### Python

The strategy I use it to build one dictionary per input list (`x`, `y`, `z`). Each of these will act as set of labeled bins. For each input list, bin `i` will contain the items for which their corresponding index in list `x` is equal to `i`. Corresponding means that they are at the same position in their respective list.

```py
def compute_bins(x, y, z):
    # You can see this as an ordered-set:
    x_bin_indexes = {a:i for i, a in enumerate(sorted(set(x)))}

    # Each input list has its own set of labeled bins: 
    x_bins = defaultdict(list)
    y_bins = defaultdict(list)
    z_bins = defaultdict(list)

    for item_x, item_y, item_z in zip(x, y, z):
        index = x_bin_indexes[item_x]
        # Drop the item in the corresponding bin:
        x_bins[index].append(item_x)
        y_bins[index].append(item_y)
        z_bins[index].append(item_z)

    # Now we transform the result back to lists of list:
    x_bins = list(x_bins.values())
    y_bins = list(y_bins.values())
    z_bins = list(z_bins.values())
    return x_bins, y_bins, z_bins
```

The key factor here is that every operation we make in the loop is in constant time. The function can be called this way:

```py
>>> xx_list, y_list, z_list = compute_bins(x, y, z)
>>> xx_list
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2]]
>>> y_list
[[1, 2, 4, 7], [3, 6], [5]]
>>> z_list
[[10, 11, 13, 16], [12, 15], [14]]
```

#### Numpy

Using numpy, I thought of a different strategy: sort all arrays according the items in `x` then split them according to the number of consecutive identical values in `x`. Here is the code (considering that `x`, `y` and `z` are numpy arrays):

```py
import numpy as np

def compute_bins(x, *others):
    x_bin_indexes, bin_sizes = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    sort_order = np.argsort(x)
    split_rule = np.cumsum(bin_sizes)[:-1]
    return tuple(np.split(o[sort_order], split_rule) for o in (x, *others))
```

Note that `np.cumsum(bin_sizes)[:-1]` is only there because `split` takes a list of index at which to cut and not a list of cut sizes. If we want to split `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]` into `[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2]]` we don't pass `[3, 2, 1]` to `np.split`, but `[3, 5]` instead.

#### Performances

Concerning performances, here is how it goes on my machine:

```py
from random import randint

test_size = int(1e6)
x = [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(test_size)]
y = [i+1 for i in range(test_size)]
z = [i+test_size+1 for i in range(test_size)]

%timeit xx_list, y_list, z_list = compute_bins(x, y, z)
```

Output for the pure **python** version:

```py
396 ms ± 5.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Output for the **numpy** version (`x`, `y` and `z` are `np.array`):

```py
105 ms ± 1.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For comparison, the solution you first proposed gives:

```py
19.7 s ± 282 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am afraid that I am using floats that are stored in the x, y and z lists. Your solution (the numpy one) throws up the following error at the " return tuple" statement: "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index". I have edited my code to better reflect the contents of the lists I am working with.

Comment: That's strange, I don't have that error, maybe that comes from the version of `numpy`. Can you try to replace the cumulative sum line by `np.cumsum(bin_sizes, dtype=np.int32)[:-1]`. Maybe I have a more recent version of numpy that understands on its own that indexes are integers, and your version doesn't know that yet :p. Or maybe it doesn't know that summing integers will only produce integers. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Sorry, I realised that the error was because I was sending lists and not numpy arrays to the function. I also had to replace *others with y,z. Is that expected?

Comment: If you are talking about the call `compute_bins(x, y, z)` then yes that's normal, if you talk about the signature of the function then no, you shouldn't have to modify it. Basically `*others` in the function signature means _group all remaining arguments in a variable (tuple) named `others`_. For example if we define f as `def f(x, *others): print(type(others), len(others))` then we can call `f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` which will print `<class 'tuple'> 4` or call `f` with any number of arguments (at least one that will be passed as `x` then as many as we want), `f(1)` prints `<class 'tuple'> 0`.